# Is 'aerial view/map/painting' the right term for a map/painting drawn/painted from a bird's-eye view?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, sentence-construction, american-english

It was an aerial view of the city. 
It was an aerial map of the city. 
It was an aerial painting of the city.

Any other ways to say this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some synonyms you might find useful:

> It is an **aerial perspective** of the city
>
> It is a **satellite view** of the city (photograph, not map)
>
> It is a **bird's eye view** of the city
>
> It is an **aerial view** of the city
>
> It is an **ordinance survey** of the city (British english, map - not photograph)
>
> It is an **overview** of the city (somewhat archaic)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a painting, one might likely say **'a painting of an aerial view'** of the city, **'a painted map'** of the city, or perhaps **'a hand-painted map'** of the city.

**'Maps'** are typically created in this perspective, so it would likely go unmentioned as in: **'a map'** of the city.  Exceptions might call attention to their deviation from the norm: **'a 3D-perspective map'** of the city.

An **aerial painting** of the city could be ambiguous as one might believe that the painting was painted while the artist was airborne.

**'Satellite view'** or **'satellite photograph'** would be correct only for very-high altitude photography (as might be taken from a satellite.)  **'Aerial photograph'** would be a better term to use if the photo were taken from a plane, a hot-air balloon or some other airborne yet non-satellite platform.

I hope this helps!